# Minimal subset of a space with the same fundamental group as the original space

Tags: algebraic-topology, set-theory, fundamental-groups

Suppose I have a topological space $\Delta$, a point $v \in \Delta$, and $\pi_1(\Delta, v) = G$ for some group $G$. Does there exist a "minimal subset" $S$ of $\Delta$ containing $v$ such that $\pi_1(S, v) = \pi_1(\Delta, v)$?

Here was my idea:

We introduce the partial order $\leq$ on the set:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{S} := \{ S \ | \ v \in S \subseteq \Delta \ \text{and} \ \pi_1(S,v) = \pi_1(\Delta,v) \}
\end{align}

by $A \leq B \iff A \subseteq B$. We define the dual order $\leq^*$ on $\mathcal{S}$ by $A \leq^* B \iff B \leq A$. I want to apply Zorn's lemma to $\mathcal{S}$ by stating that every chain has a maximal element with respect to $\leq^*$, but I'm having trouble finding what this element should be. Obviously if $\Delta$ has trivial fundamental group, this maximal element would universally just be the singleton $\{ v \}$, but what about more complicated spaces? Is this even possible? If not, are there any additional restrictions we can place on $\Delta$ that lets us find such a subset?

Comment: Why must $\mathcal{S}$ be nonempty?

Comment: @Randall My mistake, just made an edit. $\mathcal{S}$ is always nonempty because it always contains $\Delta$

Comment: I don't see how you could ever get every chain to have a maximal element.  Homotopy groups don't preserve colimits/limits/whatever.

Comment: @Randall My motivation behind this question was in the context of 1 and 2-dimensional CW complexes. In many examples, this "minimal subset" is quite obvious. For example, let's say we had a wedge of two circles at a vertex $v$ with a tree attached to $v$. Then this "minimal subset" is simply just the wedge of two circles. It gets more complicated with 2-dimensional CW complexes, but the idea is similar - it seems like there's always some "irrelevant information" you can cut off of original space.

Comment: Try the Hawaiian earring.

Comment: @dacian98 that's not true even for a $1$-dimensional CW complex, e.g. the wedge sum of countably many copies of $S^1$. However it is an interesting question in case of a CW complex with finitely generated fundamental group.

Comment: Take a disc and remove the origin. This is a (countable) 2-complex with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$. Evidently it has no `minimal' subspace with the same fundamental group.